# Make clangd aware of macros given from the compiler

Tags: c, clangd

I have two executables that are build from the same source (a client and a server) and they're built with the compile options `-D CLIENT=0 -D SERVER=1` for the server and `-D CLIENT=1 -D SERVER=0` for the client. If I do something like

```
if (CLIENT) {
// Client specific code
}
```

clangd complains that CLIENT is not defined. Is there a way to make clangd aware of those macros? (The code compiles just fine, the errors are from `clangd`, not the compiler)

Comment: It cant be reproduced https://godbolt.org/z/b56aPsW6G

Comment: yes, `clang` compiles just fine, the problem is with `clangd`, the language server

Comment: Instead of `if (CLIENT)` which might get evaluated at run-time, depending on the optimization settings, I suggest to use `#ifdef CLIENT` or `#if CLIENT`

Comment: This is not the best way to use compile time configuration. You better use the preprocessor `#ifdef`/`ifndef` directives to conditionally compile specific code portions.

Comment: I find `if (CLIENT)` easier to read, and i'll use it if I can. It will definitely be optimized by any modern compiler anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make clangd aware of those macros?

From [getting started with clangd](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clangd/Installation.html#project-setup):

> ### Project setup
>
> To understand source code in your project, clangd needs to know the
> build flags. (This is just a fact of life in C++, source files are not
> self-contained.)
>
> By default, clangd will assume that source code is built as clang
> some_file.cc, and you’ll probably get spurious errors about missing
> #included files, etc. There are a couple of ways to fix this.
>
> #### compile_commands.json
>
> compile_commands.json file provides compile commands for all source
> files in the project. This file is usually generated by the build
> system, or tools integrated with the build system. Clangd will look
> for this file in the parent directories of the files you edit. Other
> tools can also generate this file. See the compile_commands.json
> specification.

`compile_commands.json` is typically generated with CMake build system, but more build systems try to generate it.

I would suggest moving your project to CMake, in the process you will learn this tool that will definitely help you in further C-ish development.

> #### compile_flags.txt
>
> If all files in a project use the same build flags, you can put those
> flags, one flag per line, in compile_flags.txt in your source root.
>
> Clangd will assume the compile command is clang $FLAGS some_file.cc.
>
> Creating this file by hand is a reasonable place to start if your
> project is quite simple.

If not moving to cmake, create a `compile_flags.txt` file with the content for example like the following, and `clangd` should pick this file up:

```
-DCLIENT=1
-DSERVER=1
```

Comment: If you aren't using cmake, you can also use something like [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to build compile_commands.json.

Comment: @Hasturkun: [Compiledb](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) might be a better alternative, as it does not require a project rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

How about rather than making *clangd* aware of them, make the error message
suppressed? As it is not always desired to switch the build system, nor is it always welcome to add non-essential files to all codebases.

Few people would object to adding safety checks such as these, providing more clear error messages:

```
#ifndef CLIENT
#error "CLIENT undeclared. Must be set when building."
#define CLIENT 0
#endif

#ifndef SERVER
#error "SERVER undeclared. Must be set when building."
#define SERVER 0
#endif
```

With those in place, one can suppress the *pp_hash_error* in ones *clangd.yaml*
file:

*clangd.yaml*:

```yaml
Diagnostics:
  Suppress: pp_hash_error
```

One could of course instead suppress the *undeclared_var_use* directly, without needing the safety check in the source code. However one can argue that has a high risk of hiding real errors, while explicit `#error` calls should rarely be of interest for *clangd*.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer above suggest to use `compile_flags.txt`, but it [would be ignored](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_flagstxt) if `compile_commands.json` is present.

It's suggested to add a [project configuration](https://clangd.llvm.org/config#files) `.clangd` in the root of your project. And add the compile flags manually.

```
#.clangd
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-DLAB_PGTBL, -DSOL_PGTBL]
```