How to disable coloring out the section of code between macros?
I have source files that contain macros loaded by a proprietary build toolchain. Unfortunately, Neovim doesn't have a plugin for the configuration file (emProject from SEGGER) and doesn't recognize these macros. As a result, they are not detected by clangd. Is there a way to adjust clangd's behavior?
Specifically, I would like to disable the graying out of code sections between the macros. I use Neovim, lsp-config, clangd, and mason, with all settings based on the NChad configuration.



Are you asking how to adjust clang or how to disable coloring (where "coloring" is a property of neovim)? Did you research like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887552/make-clangd-aware-of-macros-given-from-the-compiler ?

I'm uncertain how neovim evaluates those conditional directives, or whether it does so itself at all.  You might find Vi and Vim SE to be better prepared to answer this question.

@KamilCuk That is the thing I didn't know. Unfortunately HighCommander4 provided solution that works. So I was looking for the adjust of clangd.

If you're using clangd 17 or later, the coloring of inactive code regions can be disabled by adding the following to your clangd configuration:
SemanticTokens:
  DisabledKinds: [InactiveCode]


Note: the above applies to clients that do not implement the textDocument/inactiveRegions Language Server Protocol extension, and thus fall back to coloring inactive code regions using textDocument/semanticTokens.
For clients that do implement textDocument/inactiveRegions (such as vscode-clangd), there should be client-specific options for customizing the appearance of inactive regions (for example, the "clangd.inactiveRegions.useBackgroundHighlight" setting in vscode-clangd).
